# Completely replacing GitHub repo, branches and commits

Tags: git, github

I have a project in GitHub with 11 branches. This had to remain as it was while I rebuilt the project using a later version of one of the technologies.

I rebuilt the project in a private BitBucket repo. This also has 11 branches, and an entirely different commit history.

I have mirrored the original GitHub repo so that there is still public access to the 'old' code. The next step is to blow away the contents of the original GitHub repo, and replace with the contents from the BitBucket repo.

I don't want to delete / rename the GitHub repo as is has a few watchers and stars - those people should get the latest version of the code.

So the question is: **how do I delete the branches and content of a GitHub repo, and replace with the branches, content and history of a different one?**

Ideally I'd end up with the BitBucket version being the `staging` remote and GitHub the `origin`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tested this myself, but according to the [git push docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push), you should use the `--mirror` flag.

```
git push --mirror <name of github remote>
```

**Update**: I just tested it and it seems to work as I expected. It will force your remote to look exactly like your local repository including deleting/adding branches and tags and force-updating branches.

Comment: Yup. I had a github repo with only a `ReadMe.md`. I copied the readme to my local repo (started as a new flutter app in the cmd line). Did a `git init` in the VStudio terminal (on Windows). Clicked the V on the version control, and commited a "1st time" of all files. In the terminal did `git remote add origin https://github.com/myAccount/myProject` and `git push --mirror` with no params. Worked like a charm.

But problem: When I push with the vscode I get `"Can't push refs to remote. Try running 'Pull' first, to integrate your changes'.`  I did `git push -f --all` and alls ok that ends ok.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you can use force push for replacing content of GitHub repository.

```
git push -f
```

Comment: This won't replace all branches and tags.