# How to upload an updated local repo to GitHub if I previously uploaded a version already?

Tags: git, github

Believe it or not, I'm still new to GitHub. I'm using GitHub Desktop.

I previously uploaded my repo to Github, let's call it Repo A.

Now I have a version of the same code of Repo A in my localhost, let's call it Repo A++ because some code in this repo has been updated. The old .git folder is no longer available.

So, how can I add and push Repo A++ in localhost to Repo A?

My concern is when I fetch (or pull, I'm not sure) Repo A from GitHub, will it overwrite all my updated files in Repo A++?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Completely replacing GitHub repo, branches and commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427180/completely-replacing-github-repo-branches-and-commits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Repo A is on github.com Lets assume its this path:
And lets assume your directory on localhost is

```
/home/mewiben39/dev/RepoA++/
```

https://github.com/mewiben39/RepoA.git

switch to a directory some other location lets say
(below is my assumed directory)

```
cd /home/mewben39/dev/git_clones/
```

then

```
git clone https://github.com/mewben39/RepoA.git
```

this will clone your remote repo locally to (this will also contain .git folder but its hidden)

/home/mewben39/dev/git_clones/RepoA/

RepoA contains code from github.com which you want to be merged with RepoA++

Now run the below command

```
cp -rv /home/mewiben39/dev/RepoA++/*  /home/mewben39/dev/git_clones/RepoA/
```

the above cp command will copy data from RepoA++ to RepoA

now you have overwritten code from RepoA++ to RepoA on local,

then navigate to RepoA you cloned locally and `git add .`
and finally commit the code `git commit -m 'copied code from RepoA++ to RepoA' then` git push`.

Remember `git add .` is not recommended I did it as you copying code from updated RepoA++ which is you are moving entire code base.

Also, I have used this method because you mentioned you have code in RepoA++ updated.

Alliteratively you can also navigate to RepoA++ and set remote URL to `git remote set main github.com/mewiben39/repoA.git`

then git push with force flag. Using force flag is not recommended.

Comment: force flag shouldn't be needed in this case and should be avoided

Comment: @PhuNgo I agree force flag is destructive , just mentioned in alternative if its only the beginning of a repo and not much has changed..

Comment: Ok, let me digest this and try it out.